How to properly credit an author when using their project as a module in my project?
I'm new to releasing open source, or releasing any kind of code I've developed at all.
There is this Python CLI application an author posted on GitHub with an AGPL-3.0 license. I found it useful and developed a GUI for it. I want to release it on GitHub as open source and I want to include the original CLI application for convenience.
What should I do?
I wanted to contact the author to ask them directly but they had no contact information on their Github profile.

You said you're keen to release your GUI as open source.  Would you be happy to release it under AGPLv3?  If you are, it makes things very simple.

If AGPLv3 lets people do whatever they want to do with my code except unlicensed commercial usage, I'm all good. In that case, can I just release my project with AGPL3.0 and I'm all set?

AGPLv3 permits commercial usage, but with the caveat that anyone in possession of the binaries or interacting with the software over a computer network must be given access to the source, and the recipient must honour AGPLv3 in his/her turn.  Will that do you, in which case I'll write it up as an answer?  Or are you looking to ban all, or more, commercial usage?
